# Parabolic subgroup of reflection group is reflection group

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm studying hyperplane arrangements on the Orlik-Terao and I'm right now at the part about reflection arrangements.
There is a seemingly trivial proposition which is left with no proof that is:

> Given $U$ subspace and $G_U$ the subgroup of the reflection group $$G$$ that contains all $g\in G$ that fix $U$ pointwise, then $G_U$ is generated by reflections.
>   Moreover, the generators of $G_U$ are the generators of $G$ whose fixed hyperplane contains $U$

Now the reference seems incorrect, so can anyone help me with proving this proposition?

Obviously one containment is trivial, but I can't prove the other one